# JSF and Primefaces: sortyBy doesn't work (no arrows visible)

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

basically I don't know why, but those arrows next to row headers are not showing for "Oseba" column. Here is code where it's not working, where it is working and how it should look like.

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="Ni zapisov" id="dataTable" var="cont" value="#{contactsBean.contactDataModel}"
                     paginator="true" rows="20" rowKey="#{cont.idContact}"  paginatorPosition="bottom" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30" 
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                     lazy="true" style="width:100%"  sortBy="cont.firstName" sortOrder="ASCENDING" filterDelay="400">

                    <p:column headerText="Oseba" sortyBy="#{cont.cont.firstName}" filterBy="#{cont.fullName}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
                         <h:outputText value="#{cont.firstName} #{cont.lastName}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column  headerText="Naslov" sortBy="#{cont.cont.address}" filterBy="#{cont.cont.address}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{cont.address}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column  headerText="Pošta" sortBy="#{cont.cont.zip.name}" filterBy="#{cont.zipAddress}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
                         <h:outputText value="#{cont.zip.name} #{cont.zip.zipId}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column  headerText="Telefon" sortBy="#{cont.cont.phoneNum}" filterBy="#{cont.cont.phoneNum}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
                         <h:outputText value="#{cont.phoneNum}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Email" sortBy="#{cont.cont.EMail}" filterBy="#{cont.cont.EMail}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{cont.EMail}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Arnes ID" sortBy="#{cont.cont.arnesId}" filterBy="#{cont.cont.arnesId}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{cont.arnesId}" />
                    </p:column>    

                    <p:column style="width:95px;" >
                        <p:commandButton oncomplete="cDialog.show()" action="#{contactsBean.setSelectedContact(cont)}" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Podrobno"  update=":cEditForm" /> 
                        <p:commandButton oncomplete="cDialog.show()" action="#{contactsBean.editContact(cont)}" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Uredi" update=":cEditForm" style="margin-left:5px;" />
                        <p:commandButton oncomplete="deleteDialog.show()" action="#{contactsBean.setSelectedContact(cont)}" update=":deleteContactForm" title="Izbriši" icon="ui-icon-trash" style="margin-left:5px;" />  
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
```

Here it works (on different page):

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="Ni zapisov" id="dataTable" var="org" value="#{organizationBean.orgDataModel}"
                     paginator="true" rows="20" rowKey="#{org.idOrganization}"  paginatorPosition="bottom" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30" 
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                     lazy="true" style="width:100%" sortBy="org.name" sortOrder="ASCENDING" filterDelay="400">

                    <p:column headerText="Ime organizacije" filterBy="#{org.org.name}" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="org.name" style="width:435px;" >
                         <h:outputText value="#{(org.name.length()>70)? org.name.substring(0,70).concat('...') : org.name}" /> 
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column  headerText="Naslov" filterBy="#{org.org.address}" filterMatchMode="contains"  sortBy="org.address" >
                         <h:outputText value="#{org.address}" /> 
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Pošta"  sortBy="org.zip.zipId" filterBy="#{org.zipId}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{org.zip.zipId} #{org.zip.name} -  #{org.zip.country.idCountry} " />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column style="width:95px;" > 

                        <p:commandButton oncomplete="orgDialog.show()" action="#{organizationBean.setSelectedOrg(org)}" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Podrobno"  update=":orgEditForm" /> 
                        <p:commandButton oncomplete="orgDialog.show()" action="#{organizationBean.editOrg(org)}" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Uredi" update=":orgEditForm" style="margin-left:5px;" />
                        <p:commandButton oncomplete="deleteDialog.show()" action="#{organizationBean.setSelectedOrg(org)}" update=":deleteOrgForm" title="Izbriši" icon="ui-icon-trash" style="margin-left:5px;" />  

                    </p:column>
```

Visual presentation:

http://i57.tinypic.com/25hfpg8.jpg (not seeing arrows)

http://i57.tinypic.com/290zmn6.jpg (working)

So, I want to be able to sort "Oseba" column

Comment: Could you post a link to some of the generated HTML for the working and non-working cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double variable (and wrong attribute name "sort **y** By"):

```
sortyBy="#{cont.cont.firstName}"
```

if you are using PF < 4.0

```
sortBy="#{cont.firstName}"
```

else

```
sortBy="firstName"
```